# WSO2 DSS Quality of Service Configuration panel empty

Tags: wso2, wso2-data-services-server

After upgrade my DSS installation from 3.2.2 to 3.5.0 I have no options in the "Quality of Service Configuration" panel in the service dashboard. I review the documentation but I can't find anything about that change or where are the options related with security or caching now and I need to secure a service.
Someone can help my to enable that options or explain the new way to secure a service?

thanks

Comment: I have the same problem on a fresh install. could you find out whats the reason to this and how to fix?

Answer (score 0):

We are deprecating applying QoS through UI. You can do that through [Developer Studio](http://wso2.com/products/developer-studio/). Have a look on [here](https://docs.wso2.com/display/DVS350/Applying+QoS+for+a+Service)